# API Login Limit issue seen in Acumatica Standard APIs

Tags: api, integration, acumatica

We are currently running into a peculiar "API Login Limit" issue when accessing Acumatica data via the Acumatica Standard APIs.

Is there anyone here who has seen this in the past, and based on your experience how have you resolved this?

We have tried using the specific Logout API, but even executing the Logout API also shows us the login limit error as well occasionally.

Any advise/suggestions is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

We tried setting the "no of sessions" in our API as '6' and noticed that we recieve the API login limit issue after 4 or 5 consecutive API calls. Do you think we could increase the number of sessions?

Comment: If you're only reading data you can get away with just odata sometimes. Depending on how you need your data to be structured. AFAIK, odata is not covered by the API limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to ‘SM604000 to see ‘Maximum Number of Concurrent Web Services API Requests’ and other API limitations of the instance. These limitations are based on the license of the instance of Acumatica and can be increased by upgrading to a higher level license.